# Generalize a couple of actions into a Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of radio buttons on different pages. I have been trying to write a general function that takes in the id/class of that radio button list.

Example 1: Index.html

```
$("[id*='Buttonlist1']").each(function () {     
    var radios = $(this).find(":radio");
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * radios.length);
    $(radios[randomnumber]).click().mousedown();
});
```

Example 2: Dream.html

```
$(".ButtonList2").each(function () {     
    var radios = $(this).find("label");
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * radios.length);
    $(radios[randomnumber]).click().mousedown();
});
```

Notice that .find("type") is changed in the two examples. I want to pass the id/class and the type in the general function. My attempts in writing a general function have been fruitless. Anybody who can help me with the general function? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about giving two parameters like this

```
function funcName(selector, type){
  $(selector).each(function () {     

    var radios = $(this).find(type);
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * radios.length);
    $(radios[randomnumber]).click().mousedown();

  });
}
```

Call this function with different parameters

```
funcName("[id*='Buttonlist1']", ":radio"); //index.html

funcName(".ButtonList2", "label"); //dream.html
```

Comment: Ah! It was that simple. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Might be this will solve your problem

```
function commonFunction(identifier,type) {
    $(identifier).each(function () {
        var radios = $(this).find(type);
        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * radios.length);
        $(radios[randomnumber]).click().mousedown();

    });
}

commonFunction(".someClass","div");
commonFunction("#SomeID",":radio");
commonFunction("div","a");
```

Comment: Thank you. Similar to what @Jyothi has given.

Comment: Yes.. just 1 min. late .. ;-)

Thanks